# Why does css selector return different length from jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have noticed that these two expressions return different length (Check the console):

```js
var cssSelector =  $('#target').siblings('table > tbody > tr > td').length; // returns 0
var jQuerySelector =  $('#target').siblings('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length; // returns 1
console.log('cssSelector: ' + cssSelector);
console.log('jQuerySelector: ' + jQuerySelector);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Target</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would expect that they both select the same element, so they would return the same result.

Comment: For the record, `.siblings()` and `.children()` are traversal methods, not selectors. `table > tbody > tr > td` is a selector. In the context of a jQuery call, it's a jQuery selector. It only happens to also be a valid CSS selector, but that is not pertinent in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.siblings('table > tbody > tr > td')` matches `td` elements. You can tell because the subject of the selector is `td`. Since `#target`'s sibling is a `table`, not a `td`, this won't match anything.

`.siblings('table')` matches `table` elements. You then follow up with a series of `.children()` calls that drills down to the table's `td` descendants, producing a successful match.

Answer (score 1):

because `table` is sibling of `#target` and you are saying that `td` is sibling in your `var cssSelector`, which isn't correct, because `td` is a child of the `table`.

```js
var cssSelector =  $('#target').siblings('table').length; // returns 1
var jQuerySelector =  $('#target').siblings('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length; // returns 1
console.log('cssSelector: ' + cssSelector);
console.log('jQuerySelector: ' + jQuerySelector);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Target</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `$('#target').siblings('table')` gives table which is a sibling of `#target` and then you need to parse through its children by `.find("tbody > tr > td")`

```js
var cssSelector =  $('#target').siblings('table').find("tbody > tr > td").length; // returns 0
var jQuerySelector =  $('#target').siblings('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length; // returns 1
console.log(cssSelector);
console.log(jQuerySelector);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Target</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Cell</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```